# IE8 XHTML returned in jQuery ajax call issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xhtml, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue I cannot resolve through trying lots of different methods!!

Works in Chrome, FF, IE9 but not IE8 or IE7

**Overview**

I have a page, that Ajax's in the whole HTML from a local .aspx of which reads a photobucket XML feed puts into an HTML list and returns.

http://custommodsuk.com/Gallery.aspx

I've done it this way so the page ranking isn't penilised by Google speed rankings, as the server would be going off and making the call.

**The code**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: ajaxURL,
                dataType:'html',
                success: function (feedHTML) {

                    var galleryList = $(feedHTML).find('#galleryList').find('.listItem');
                    var noItems = galleryList.length;

                   console.log(feedHTML.type);

                    galleryList.each(function (index) {
                        ...
                    });
                }
            });
```

**What I've tried**

As you can see the console.log(), 
the type is undefined, the feedHTML.length shows no. of characters. And from what I gather is generally treated as a string.

It is the JQuery not being able to turn the response into a jQuery object, and I can't traverse it.  Therefore the each won't cycle.

I've seen lots of people with the same/similar issue on SO, but no answers, partly due to crap code examples.

Comment: I don't see any ajax call being made from that page.

Comment: Oh, I'm using XHTML witht he appropriate doc type.

Comment: Pointy, it's happening... GET /Gallery/GalleryGet.aspx HTTP/1.1

Comment: Ah OK; my Firebug was stuck.  Well, there's no ".type" method you can expect on strings; try `typeof feedHTML` maybe.

Comment: Also your markup in the table cells is not valid; you've got `<p>` elements that start inside `<span>` elements. That might be upsetting the parser.

Comment: Yeh sorry Type of is string, my bad.  I don't think the specification requirements of blocks in inline's such as p's in span would upset DOM handling... though your right and have changed spans to divs... Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Photobuckets RSS feed is malformed.

```
<p><a href="http://s1174.photobucket.com/albums/r614/CustomModsUK/">CustomModsUK</a> posted a photo</a></p>
```

This tripped up IE8.  If you ever have problems like this in the future, check the validity of the HTML!!!